# Is it possible for a javascript class to define a method which fires if the class is called?

Tags: javascript, class

In python there's something like `__call__` for this. Consider the following example:

```
class MyClass {
  __call__() { return 'called!' }
}

const myType = new MyClass();
myType(); // called!
```

The question is what should I replace `__call__` with?

I was doing some research, and most of the answers recommend `__proto__`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `__proto__` is not a method at all. The thing that gets executed when you create a class *is the constructor*.

Comment: `myClass` is a misleading variable name. It is not a class, but an instance of a class.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible out-of-the-box, but you can extend `Function`, and use the `Function` constructor to forward a call to `__call__`. If you have multiple classes that need this feature, extend `Function` only once into -- let's  say -- a `Callable` class, and then inherit your other classes from that:

```js
class Callable extends Function {
    constructor() {
        super("...args", "return this.__call__(...args)");
        return this.bind(this);
    }
}

class Class extends Callable {
    __call__() { return 'called!' }
}

let inst = new Class();
console.log(inst());
```

#### Background

In JavaScript an object is callable when, and only if, it has the [[Call]] internal slot. But there is (currently) no way to give any given object this slot via JavaScript code. One must start with a function object and extend that.

#### Adding a constructor, inheritance

The above solution allows the constructor to define properties in the usual way: the constructed object is an instance of the class:

```js
class Callable extends Function {
    constructor() {
        super("...args", "return this.__call__(...args)");
        return this.bind(this);
    }
}

class Class extends Callable {
    constructor(data) { 
        super();
        this.x = data;
    }
    __call__() { return 'called!' }
}

let inst = new Class(42);
console.log(inst instanceof Class); // true
console.log(inst.x); // 42
console.log(inst());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use constructor.

```
class Example {
  constructor() {
    // gets called on class initialization
  }
}
```

Inside the constructor you can also call other methods if you want.

However this won't create an invoke function like using PHP's __invoke if that's what you meant.  If that's what you're looking for then I don't know.